# adding new letters/symbols from character map? How do you do it?

Tags: edit-mode

[image]

I can't just copy and paste a symbol from the character map app to the text box I add into my project

Answer (score 1):

You can't paste this symbols because standard blender font has no this symbols.

Select different font, that has this specific symbol (for example Times new roman), from your text object here:

[image]